# Spring Boot Actuator 2.5.6 Micrometer NoSuchMethod

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, datasource, spring-boot-actuator

During run of `Spring Boot 2.5.6` application I'm experiencing problem with `micrometer` when trying to open transaction in `@Transactional` code. The problem does not exist when there is no `actuator` on the classpath.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'io.micrometer.core.instrument.distribution.DistributionStatisticConfig$Builder io.micrometer.core.instrument.distribution.DistributionStatisticConfig$Builder.serviceLevelObjectives(double[])'
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.metrics.PropertiesMeterFilter.configure(PropertiesMeterFilter.java:86) ~[spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at io.micrometer.core.instrument.MeterRegistry.getOrCreateMeter(MeterRegistry.java:568) ~[micrometer-core-1.3.5.jar:1.3.5]
    at io.micrometer.core.instrument.MeterRegistry.registerMeterIfNecessary(MeterRegistry.java:529) ~[micrometer-core-1.3.5.jar:1.3.5]
    at io.micrometer.core.instrument.MeterRegistry.timer(MeterRegistry.java:269) ~[micrometer-core-1.3.5.jar:1.3.5]
    at io.micrometer.core.instrument.Timer$Builder.register(Timer.java:473) ~[micrometer-core-1.3.5.jar:1.3.5]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.metrics.micrometer.MicrometerMetricsTracker.<init>(MicrometerMetricsTracker.java:83) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.metrics.micrometer.MicrometerMetricsTrackerFactory.create(MicrometerMetricsTrackerFactory.java:21) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.setMetricsTrackerFactory(HikariPool.java:309) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:118) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager.doBegin(DataSourceTransactionManager.java:265) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
```

On the first glance it looks like all Spring libs are in the same version, however we have some weird parent POM which I overriden in this app POM.

Update.

The same problem exists whenever calling  `/actuator` endpoint - the call returns payload, but logs log error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'io.micrometer.core.instrument.distribution.DistributionStatisticConfig$Builder io.micrometer.core.instrument.distribution.DistributionStatisticConfig$Builder.serviceLevelObjectives(double[])'
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.metrics.PropertiesMeterFilter.configure(PropertiesMeterFilter.java:86) ~[spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at io.micrometer.core.instrument.MeterRegistry.getOrCreateMeter(MeterRegistry.java:568) ~[micrometer-core-1.3.5.jar:1.3.5]
    at io.micrometer.core.instrument.MeterRegistry.registerMeterIfNecessary(MeterRegistry.java:529) ~[micrometer-core-1.3.5.jar:1.3.5]
    at io.micrometer.core.instrument.MeterRegistry.timer(MeterRegistry.java:269) ~[micrometer-core-1.3.5.jar:1.3.5]
    at io.micrometer.core.instrument.Timer$Builder.register(Timer.java:473) ~[micrometer-core-1.3.5.jar:1.3.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.getTimer(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:161) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.lambda$record$0(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:139) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.AutoTimer.apply(AutoTimer.java:109) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.record(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:138) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:103) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:540) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:895) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1722) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) ~[na:na]
```

Comment: This can only come from an incompatible version, someting is managing the micrometer dependency to some other version (older or newer) that isn't compatible.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks, that was the reason - dependency hell... :)